# Run java program as a scheduler without using crontab

Tags: java, scripting

I've a main program which performs some task in Java. I want to run it as a batch job & due to our policies, I'm not allowed to use crontab where I can configure it.

What's the alternate option for me? How can I schedule my Java program to run once a day??

Any sample wrapper code will be helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to schedule your job in Java or Bash. If you try to implement in Java, you can try to create a [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for your job, and let the thread sleep for a period:

```
class repeatTask extends Thread
{
    int repeatTime;

    public repeatTask(int repeatTime)
    {
        this.repeatTime = repeatTime;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(repeatTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /* Some action codes here*/
        }
    }
}
```

And also you can use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, which could also let you create a thread:

```
public void start()
{
    timerSchedule();            
}

public void timerSchedule()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            /*Action codes here*/
        }
    }, /*Repeat Time here*/);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`at`](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/at.1.php) - execute commands at a later time
and/or  combine it with [`sleep`](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/sleep.1.php) - delay for a specified amount of time
on a loop, running in the background

for example, say you have the follow script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    java -jar your.jar.file
    sleep 24h # wait one day
done
```

run it as

```
bash script && disown &
```

Answer (score 2):

> ... due to our policies, I'm not allowed to use crontab where I can configure it.

Clearly, there must be some reason for this policy, though it is not obvious what it is.  Any alternative scheme could *potentially* fall foul of the same reasoning  that caused them to forbid `cron`.  (Certainly, some of the alternatives proposed above are likely to be *worse* than `cron`.)

The best thing to do is to ask the people who set this policy to tell you the *approved* way to schedule a job.  Or at least ask them to explain why the use of `cron` is forbidden so that you have some idea what to avoid in any alternative scheme you come up with.

(OK, it is possible that the policy is a stupid knee-jerk reaction to some problem in the past.  But, you still need to understand what the problem was ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use java timer tasks

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) for things like this: see if that works for you. You can use that for the scheduling bits, and just run a standard Java program.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It's scheduling formats are very similar to crontab.